# how to get the 3rd report to combine the customer and order data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a question about retention rate.
I have 2 tables, including the customer data and the order data.

```
 DISTRIBUTOR as d
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
|   ID    | SETUP_DT  | REINSTATE_DT | LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT |
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | Null         | Null               |
| C111112 | 2015/12/9 | 2018/10/25   | 2018/10/25         |
| C111113 | 2018/10/1 | Null         | Null               |
| C111114 | 2018/10/6 | 2018/12/14   | 2018/12/14         |
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
```

```
 ORDER as o, please noted that the data is for reference...
+---------+----------+-----+
|   ID    |  ORD_DT  | OAL |
+---------+----------+-----+
| C111111 | 2018/1/1 | 112 |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1 | 100 |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1 | 472 |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1 | 452 |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1 | 248 |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1 | 996 |
+---------+----------+-----+
```

```
 The 3rd Table in my mind to create the retention rate report
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
|   ID    |  APP_MON  | ORDER_MON | TimeDiff(Mon) | TTL AMT |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/1/1  |             - |  25,443   |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/2/1  |             1 |  7,610    |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/3/1  |             2 |  20,180   |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/4/1  |             3 |  22,265   |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/5/1  |             4 |  34,118   |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/6/1  |             5 |  19,523   |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/7/1  |             6 |  20,220   |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/8/1  |             7 |  2,006    |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/9/1  |             8 |  15,813   |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/10/1 |             9 |  16,733   |
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/11/1 |            10 |  20,973   |
| C111112 | 2018/10/1 | 2017/11/1 |             - |  516      |
| C111112 | 2018/10/1 | 2018/10/1 |             - |  1        |
| C111113 | 2018/10/1 | Null      |             - | Null      |
| C111114 | 2018/12/1 | Null      |             - | Null      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+

Definition:
- APP_MON: the month that the customer joined, which is the max date from the start date of [d.SETUP_DT], [d.REINSTATE_DT] and [d.LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT]
- ORD_MON: the month that the customer purchased, which is the start date of the order date month
- TimeDiff: The duration by month between APP_MON and ORD_MON, e.g. if A's ODR_MON is 2018/1/1 and A'S APP_MON is 2018/2/1, the duration is 1.
- TTL_AMT: the total order amount that the customer bought in the related order date month
```

I tried to get the data from 3rd table.
But I run the code below and it's very slow... I need a more effective way since I have millions of data...
Thanks.

Comment: Based on your code, I've removed the `sql-server` tag and added an `oracle` tag instead. SQL Server and oracle are different products and using different dialect of SQL.

Comment: You've tagged both SQL Server and Oracle here; what RDBMS are you *really* using. I would suggest Oracle, as `TO_DATE` and `trunc` aren't a T-SQL functions. As for help, it'll be really helpful to the volunteers if you post sample data and expected results; preferable as DDL and DML statements, but otherwise as **formatted** `text`.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: As for performance, as well, I suspect a problem with be `and trunc(o.ORD_DT,'MM') BETWEEN` I don't know Oracle, but that clause looks to me to be non-SARGable. Edit: Looks like that is the case, according to this article, https://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sql/indexes/where-clause.html, which states *"all predicates on the column `{column name}` must include `TRUNC()`"*. You only have `o.ORD_DT` in your `GROUP  BY`, thus it won't be SARGable, based on that reading.

Comment: if you can please share the table structure as well might make a lil more clear

Comment: @Larnu - given that the tasks is to retrieve two years' worth of data from tables with millions of rows it is highly unlikely that indexed reads would be the most efficient way of executing this query. So it really doesn't matter whether the access criteria are sargable.

Comment: I edited the question and added the sample data, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `unpivot`. To get the latest date you can just use the `greatest()` function.

This solution has two subqueries, one to calculate the `app_mon` for each new customer and the other to calculate the earliest order date for all customers who placed an order in the last two years. This may not be the most performative approach but your first priority should be to get the correct outcome; once you have that you can tune it if necessary:

```
with cust as 
(
    select d.dist_id as id
          , greatest(d.setup_dt, d.reinstate_dt, d.local_reinstate_dt) as app_mo 
    from mjensen_dev.gc_distributor d
    where d.setup_dt >= date '2017-01-01'
    or d.reinstate_dt >= date '2017-01-01'
    or d.local_reinstate_dt >= date '2017-01-01'
) , ord as 
(
    select o.dist_id as id
          , min(o.ord_dt) as ord_mon 
          , sum(o.oal) as ord_amt
    from gc_orders o
    where o.ord_dt >= date '2017-01-01'
    group by o.dist_id
          , trunc(o.ord_dt,'mm')
)
select cust.dist_id as id
       , cust.app_mon
       , ord.ord_mon
       , floor(months_between(ord.ord_mon, cust.app_mon ) as mon_diff
       , sum(o.oal) as ord_amt
from cust
     inner join gc_orders o on cust.id = o.dist_id
order by 1, 2
/
```

You may wish to tweak at my calculation of `mon_diff`. This calculation treats 2018/2/1 - 2018/1/1 as one month difference. Because it seems odd to me that a customer who places an order on the day they joined would have a `mon_diff` of 1 rather than zero. But if your statement of the business rule is correct you would need to add 1 to the calculation. Likewise I have not included the `trunc()` in the processing of the dates but you may wish to reinstate it.

Comment: Hi @APC, the mon_diff is ok to us. And I tried use `min()` in the select query to replace `trunc()`; I found the speed is faster. Do you know the reason? Thanks.

Comment: The date columns include NULL, so I use the code to find the greatest value:  `(greatest(d.SETUP_DT, coalesce(d.REINSTATE_DT, d.SETUP_DT), coalesce(d.LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT, d.SETUP_DT))) as APP_MON`

Comment: I found that I can't get the full month from  `floor(months_between()`. e.g. if I have to count the mon_diff from 2018/6/1 to 2018/71, it would show '0' instead of '1'...

Comment: Really? I wrote a SQL Fiddle with those date values and it returns `1`. [Check it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8139/1)