# The difference between CASE and UPIVOT to find the max date across the columns; ORA-00904 wrong message

Tags: sql, oracle

I have millions of IDs and I need to find the max date from 3 different dates for each ID.
Then, I need the start date of the month of the max date.
Here's a reference:

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
|   ID    |  SETUP_DT |  REINSTATE_DT | LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT |
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | Null          | Null               |
| C111112 | 2015/12/9 | 2018/10/25    | 2018/10/25         |
| C111113 | 2018/10/1 | Null          | Null               |
| C111114 | 2018/10/6 | 2018/12/14    | 2018/12/14         |
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
```

And what I want is below:

```
+---------+-----------+
|   ID    |  APP_MON  |
+---------+-----------+
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  |
| C111112 | 2018/10/1 |
| C111113 | 2018/10/1 |
| C111114 | 2018/12/1 |
+---------+-----------+
```

I try different code to get the result.

When I used `case` and `unpivot` to find some specific IDs, the result looks all fine.

```
/* case */
SELECT DIST_ID as ID, 
trunc(
case
    when REINSTATE_DT is not null and LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT is not null then greatest(LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT, REINSTATE_DT)
    when REINSTATE_DT is null and LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT is not null then LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT
    when REINSTATE_DT is not null and LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT is null then REINSTATE_DT
    else SETUP_DT
end, 'MM') AS CN_APP_MON
FROM DISTRIBUTOR
where DIST_ID in ('CN111111','CN111112','CN111113','CN111114');

/* unpivot */
SELECT DIST_ID as ID, 
trunc(MAX(Date_value),'MM') AS CN_APP_MON 
FROM DISTRIBUTOR
UNPIVOT (Date_value FOR Date_type IN (SETUP_DT, REINSTATE_DT, LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT))
where DIST_ID in ('CN111111','CN111112','CN111113','CN111114')
GROUP BY DIST_ID;
```

However, when I change the condition and tried to use the date period to pull out the data, the result is weird.
To be more specific, I tried to replace

```
where DIST_ID in ('CN111111','CN111112','CN111113','CN111114')` <br>
```

by

```
where REINSTATE_DT
between TO_DATE('2018/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') and TO_DATE('2018/01/02','yyyy/mm/dd')`
```

But the unpivot function was not work. It showed:

> ORA-00904: "REINSTATE_DT": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

I want to know:

1. Which method is more efficient, or what else more efficient way to do that?
2. Why the unpivot method didn't work? What difference is between the 2 methods?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dates are stored as dates, you can do this using `greatest()`.  I'm not a fan of "magic" values in queries, so I like `coalesce()` for this purpose.

All your rows seem to have a `setup_dt` it can be used as a "default" using `coalesce()`.  So:

```
select id,
       trunc(greatest(setup_dt,
                      coalesce(reinstate_dt, setup_dt,
                      coalesce(local_reinstate_dt, setup_dt)
                     ),
             'mm') as app_mon
from distributor;
```

Comment: Hmmm, I advised Chrissy to use `greatest()` in [their strikingly similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914420/146325). They ignored my post, I wonder if they'll pay any more attention today?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But, I can't use greatest(). If I use greatest(), the max value would be "null. That's not what I need.

Comment: @Chrissy . . . As I say in the answer, if `setup_dt` is not `null` -- as in all your sample data -- then that will never happen.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff that's great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need such daunting tasks, `greatest` with `nvl` function resolves your problem.

```
with distributor( ID, setup_dt, reinstate_dt, local_reinstate_dt ) as
(
 select 'C111111',date'2018-01-01', Null, Null from dual union all
 select 'C111112',date'2015-12-09',date'2018-10-25',date'2018-10-25' from dual union all 
 select 'C111113',date'2018-10-01',Null,Null from dual union all
 select 'C111114',date'2018-10-06',date'2018-12-14',date'2018-12-14' from dual
)
 select id, trunc(greatest(nvl(setup_dt,date'1900-01-01'), 
                           nvl(reinstate_dt,date'1900-01-01'), 
                           nvl(local_reinstate_dt,date'1900-01-01')),'mm') 
                 as app_mon
   from distributor;

  ID     APP_MON
------- ----------
C111111 01.01.2018
C111112 01.10.2018
C111113 01.10.2018
C111114 01.12.2018
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/NPY89229)

*P.S.: Using `SETUP_DT`, `REINSTATE_DT` or `LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT` columns can not be allowed In your query's `where` clause, because they are converted to `Date_type` in the `unpivot` part.*

Comment: Thanks, @Barbaros Özhan. I learn how to use nvl / isnull from you!

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan, I would use the same logic but rewrite the code as below: `SELECT DIST_ID as ID, 
    trunc(greatest(SETUP_DT,
        nvl(REINSTATE_DT, SETUP_DT),
        nvl(LOCAL_REINSTATE_DT, SETUP_DT)
    ),'MM') AS CN_APP_MON`. Is it slower or?

Comment: @Chrissy you're welcome. No, it wouldn't yield performance problem.